# Ruby on Rails: Get specific substring out of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

a little help with getting data out of a string.

Assuming I executed a sql query and now have a string(which set as hash on db):

```
"{\"users_associated\":{\"User:4\":6,\"User:22\":28,\"User:30\":36}}"
```

(Which stands for User:ID : User.display_id)

How can I get a substring the includes all users ids or all their display ids, so I'll have something like `4,22,30` or `6,22,36`)?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like JSON. You can use a JSON parser on this string

Comment: It smells even more like a X&Y question. Why do you have a string that looks like JSON in the db in the first place? Use native JSON columns instead so that you can search them in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common for data systems to return data in a serialized form, i.e. using data types that facilitate transmission of data. One of these serializable data types is `String`, which is how your JSON data object has been received.

The first step would be to de-serialize (or parse) this `String` into a `Hash` object using `JSON.parse` and tease out just the data value for key "users_associated".

```
your_string = "{\"users_associated\":{\"User:4\":6,\"User:22\":28,\"User:30\":36}}"

hash = JSON.parse(your_string)
data = hash["users_associated"]

#=> {"User:4":6, "User:22": 28, "User:30": 36}
```

`Hash#keys` gives you an array of a hash's keys.
`Hash#values` gives you an array of a hash's data values.

```
keys = data.keys
#=> ["User:4", "User:22", "User:30"]

values = data.values
#=> [6, 28, 36]
```

`Array#join` lets you string together the contents of an array with a defined separator, `,` in this case.

```
display_ids = keys.join(',')
#=> "6,28,36"
```

For the User IDs, you could `Array#map` every element of the `values` array to replace every string occurrence of "User:" with "", using `String#gsub`.

```
user_ids = values.map{|user_id| user_id.gsub("User:", "")}
#=> ["4", "22", "30"]
```

Then, in a similar way to `display_ids`, we can `Array#join` the contents of the `user_ids` array to a single string.

```
user_ids = user_ids.join(",")
#=> "4,22,30"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two helper methods. I'm leaving return values as arrays because I assume you would need to iterate on them at some point and also converting the user id's to integers.

```
def extract_display_ids(json)
  json['users_associated'].values
end

def extract_user_ids(some_data)
  json['users_associated'].keys.map{ |key| key.split(':').last.to_i }
end

some_data = JSON.parse("{\"users_associated\":{\"User:4\":6,\"User:22\":28,\"User:30\":36}}")

extract_display_ids(some_data)
#=> [6, 28, 36]
extract_user_ids(some_data)
#=> [4, 22, 30]
```

If possible though, I would recommend trying to get a better data format:

```
{ users_associated:
  [{ user_id : 4, display_id:6 }, { user_id : 4, display_id:6 }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote class for this. If you want, you can add it to your project and use it as follows:

```
require 'json'

class UserSubstringExtractor
  def initialize(user_json_data)
    @user_json_data = user_json_data
  end

  def display_ids
    user_data.dig('users_associated').values
  end

  def user_ids
    user_data.dig('users_associated').keys.map { |u| u.split(':').last.to_i }
  end

  private

  def user_data
    JSON.parse(@user_json_data)
  end
end

user_json_data = '{"users_associated":{"User:4":6,"User:22":28,"User:30":36}}'
extractor = UserSubstringExtractor.new(user_json_data)

p extractor.display_ids
#=> [6, 28, 36]
p extractor.user_ids
#=> [4, 22, 30]
```